# How many leaderboards can I have in Android via Google Play?

Tags: android, multiplayer, leaderboards, google-play

Question is simple. I have one game with multiple levels(say around 90) distributed amongts different amongst  different worlds.
Am I reading this right and it means I can only have 70 individual leaderboards or is there an alternative (grouping levels/worlds, api, etc)?

Just to be clear, additional information is:

I want to implement level based score, that is one leaderboard for each level (so players can see their score on a level by level basis), one leaderboard for each world, and one leaderboard for the whole game.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the official information about the leaderboard feature of the play-store](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#multiple_leaderboards), you can have up to a maximum of 70 leaderboards per application.

> Games can have multiple leaderboards, up to a maximum of 70. For
>   example, a multi-level game might provide a different leaderboard for
>   each level, and a racing game might have a separate leaderboard for
>   each track.

When this isn't enough for your case, you will have to develop and host your own leaderboard system on your own server.

Comment: But one guy mentioned [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115349/google-leaderboards-up-to-a-maximum-of-70) that he was able to implement more than 70 leaderboards.