# Google leaderboards, up to a maximum of 70?

Tags: leaderboards, google-play-services

I see in the doc that the limit for the [number of leaderboards on Google Play Services is 70](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#multiple_leaderboards). However, I am able to create more than 70 leaderboards and they are all working when I test my app. Is this limit still up to date? Does this mean that if I publish my game some of the leaderboards will be deactivated or something?

Thank you in advance if you know the answer. I just want to make sure of what I can expect for when I publish my game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the [documentation says the limit is 70](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#multiple_leaderboards), you should rely on the limit being 70. That's about as official as you can get, in the general case.

To do otherwise is to rely on undocumented behavior that may only work during development or local testing -- such things are typical, for example you may be able to create more than 70 for testing purposes or over the lifetime of your application but can only have 70 active on the live services at a time. This facilitates debugging or retiring older leaderboards in favor of newer ones, et cetera.

Trying to have more will likely result in the extras being disabled, or possibly prevent your app from being available until the issue is corrected.

Comment: You just rephrased the question as a statement with guesswork thrown in, rather than answering any of the specifics of the question. I guess the asker was satisfied, but this seems like a situation where it would have been better to let people with specific answers respond to the question first.

Comment: @user45623 I understand your criticism of the answer, but I'm not sure what you mean re: "this seems like a situation..." I wasn't the first person to answer (that would be Balint), and the first answers were posted after two weeks of inactivity on the question (after, iirc, the asker decided to set the bounty on it).

Comment: Good point; I didn't check the dates.

Answer (score 5):

One of my friends experience the same. They got truncated once the app was uploaded to the google play.

Answer (score 3):

Will they be deactivated?

## Yes.

The 70 leaderboard limit is part of the store specification, so more than seventy are allowed for testing on a local environment, which I have found myself, and from testimony of a few friends. The [documentation refers to Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#multiple_leaderboards), so the limit will be enforced upon publishing